# Disable screen lock when Cordova app is running

Tags: cordova

I don't know where to start. I am searching for this from yesterday but didn't got any idea.

I have a Cordova android app. It is working fine but if user is not doing anything then screen get locked and app will go to background/pause.

I want to keep the phone stay awake when app is running.

Is there any plugins/example for the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [this plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin) in order to prevent device from falling asleep.

In order to achive that you can call this method:

```
window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake()
```

And then, to enable it again, you have to use:

```
window.plugins.insomnia.allowSleepAgain()
```

Please look at the Github page for more details